# Does nuget support one package referencing another package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

Does Nuget (latest version, ie 3.4.4-rtm-1321) allow one package to reference/include another package as a dependency? I can't get this to work and I wonder if I am chasing butterflies:

A VS2015 solution contains ProjectA and ProjectB. ProjectC is independent, in a different solution.

I have PackageA built from ProjectA (builds DLL-A) in my solution.

ProjectA references ProjectB (builds DLL-B), and also references PackageC (containing DLL-C)

Project B also references PackageC (containing DLL-C).

However when I install PackageA in another solution, only DLL-A and DLL-B are installed/referenced in the target project. I have to install PackageC in order to reference DLL-C.

Both packages are built with the -IncludeReferencedProjects argument, eg:

```
nuget.exe pack <project>.csproj -Prop Configuration=Release -Prop Platform=x86 -IncludeReferencedProjects
```

This means that if I install my PackageA in a solution, it doesn't bring all its dependencies (eg DLL-C) with it and they have to be separately installed. Am I missing something or is this broken?

Update: I notice that the PackageA lib folder does not include DLL-C, which could point to the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly what the -IncludeReferenced**Projects** does.

> includereferencedprojects - Indicates that the built package should
>   include referenced projects either as dependencies or as part of the
>   package. If a referenced project has a corresponding nuspec file that
>   has the same name as the project, then that referenced project is
>   added as a dependency. Otherwise, the referenced project is added as
>   part of the package.

So when you pack the ProjectA which references ProjectB (builds DLL-B), and also references **PackageC** (containing DLL-C) with this option, NuGet will include the ProjectA DLL-A and reference ProjectB DLL-B, not include ProjectC DLL-C. Because this option only include the reference **project** not **package**. So if you want PackageA lib folder include DLL-B and DLL-C, you need set ProjectA references ProjectB, and also references **ProjectC** rather than PackageC.

Hope that can help you.

Comment: ProjectC is not in the solution (why should/would it be?) so the only way of referencing it in ProjectA is as a package. It doesn't make sense if I have to add both PackageA and PackageC to my target solution. How would I know, for example, that PackageA needs DLL-C?